# Clicking a found element of a website after locating it via xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I would like to used click method in automating view details in products which is offered in facebook market. Below is the script I created. It will go the the page however it will not click the product which is pointed in the xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Ryzen 5\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/109480902404412/search/?category_id=computers&query=Mac")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/div/div/a/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div').click()
```

Comment: You never call the .click() method.

Comment: he does though after `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: did you check what element this big string returnes? does it return anything? do you get an error? did you try to debug it using a smaller and easiert parsable html?

Comment: You might want to look into [this](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) documentation describing how to wait for the page to finish loading before interacting with it. You did not add what kind of error you are recieving but it might have something to do with trying to click the element before it has finished loading.

Comment: No Such Element Exception

Comment: Yeah then try to introduce the wait as maybe the site just hasn't finished loading yet.

Comment: NameError: name 'ElementNotSelectableException' is not defined <script src="https://gist.github.com/yeuhanshen/af1703620d599da7a2911013f8dd63fb.js"></script>

Answer (score -1):

If this method not work, you can use pyautogui and this library provides to click specific coordinates on screen.
Like this;

```
pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False
pyautogui.moveTo(Lix,Liy)
pyautogui.click(Lix,Liy,clicks=1,interval=0.0,button="left")
```

Comment: If someone ask "I do X and its not working" - answering with "you can use Y to do it" might not be the asked for help. The projekt most probably ueses selenium in other things as well. Using "Specific coordinates on the screen" is more usable for a GUI and less for a non-visual browser. using fixed coords on a website is also bad due to them changing layout depending on screenestate and moving the things around...